# Effect of crystal growth on its scintillation

Tags: crystals

How does crystal growth affect its scintillation properties? What are possible ways in which growth of CaWO crystals grown via [Chochralski method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czochralski_process) could be modified to avoid non-linearity in its scintillation output with respect to incident Gamma rays? Apparently this is relevant for rare event searches (eg. [CRESST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryogenic_Rare_Event_Search_with_Superconducting_Thermometers)) using these scintillating crystals as detectors.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a homework question since there is no real evidence of an attempt at answering it. Questions to ponder:

1. What causes scintillation, and how do the crystal properties impact that?
2. What about crystal growth might affect the relevant properties?
3. More specifically, how does Czochralski growth differ from other methods (e.g. float zone), and how would that impact the crystal properties.

Lots of fun physics and materials science bundled into the general topic, so dig into your textbooks and learn some neat stuff.